# How to get children elements from a Page that's embedded in a FlipView?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, children, flipview

I'm writing an XAML view that has a FlipView inside it. I've added 3 XAML Pages to the FlipView.Items collection. Some of those Pages have TextBlocks inside and I want to pass some data to the inner Pages that will be written in those TextBlocks.

How can I do it? It seems FlipViews don't have a Children collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the name of text block you like to change then use this function to get instance of them: FrameworkElement.FindName

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname(v=win.10).aspx

Other way, user MVVM pattern to display data on UI.